# mod_ewrite + regex to append 0 to query string parameters

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I have urls like this one...

```
https://localhost/index.php?com=liste-cat-lieux&t=41&l=6088
```

that i need to rewrite like this :

```
https://localhost/index.php?com=liste-cat-lieux&t=41&l=06088
```

I tried to append a leading 0

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(com=liste-cat-lieux&t=\d{2,3}&l=)(\d{4})$
RewriteRule ^index\.php /index?%10%2 [R=301,L]
```

It seemed to work fine when i tested it with tools like https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/, but it does not actually works in htaccess or apache

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "does not actually works"? Do you get an error? Incorrect redirect? Nothing? This is a redirect, not a "rewrite" as you have described it - is that correct? You are missing `.php` in the target URL. Where have you put this rule and what other directives do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your redirect rule appears correct but there is one problem. It doesn't check for existing leading zero this resulting in `0123` to `00123` and so on.

I suggest you keep your redirect rule to this:

```bash
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(com=liste-cat-lieux&t=\d{2,3}&l=)([1-9]\d{3})$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php /$0?%10%2 [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

Here pattern `[1-9]\d*` matches parameter value `l` that starts with digits 1 to 9 followed by 0 or more digits.

Also note use of `/$0` in redirect URL that keeps same matched URI from `RewriteRule` which is `/index.php`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable suggestion. It works as expected.

Comment: "there is one problem. It doesn't check for existing leading zero this resulting in 01234 to 001234" - But does it need to check for a leading zero? The OP is checking for exactly 4 digits, so it wouldn't have redirected `01234` to `001234`. Maybe the intention is to simply pad 4-digits to 5-digits with a leading zero? From the question description, redirecting `0001` to `00001` would not be an error. @jacquesseite

Comment: Good point @MrWhite I had a typo and it is fixed. However OP did write `I tried to append a leading 0` which mean intent is to add a single leading `0` hence making it to `0123 to 00123` is undesirable.

Comment: @MrWhite You are right. I needed to add a leading zero only when there was 4 digits. The problem was i was missing .php in the target url, as you pointed out. So, your comment contained the correct answer. 
And anubhava rewrite rule was working because there was not this .php missing.